# Get the right string through regexp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following hypothetical values of a string:

```
//start string:
var text1 = 'Me & You';
var text2 = 'Me& You';
var text3 = 'Me &You';
var text4 = 'Me&You';
var text5 = 'Me        &You';
var text6 = 'Me&       You';
var text7 = 'Me     &  You';
//Final string I want to get:
text1: Me You
text2: Me You
text3: Me You
text4: MeYou
text5: Me        You
text6: Me       You
text7: Me       You
//real output:
text1: Me You
text2: Me You
text3: Me &You
text4: MeYou
text5: Me        //Here are many hidden spaces
//and similar outputs
//hypothetical RegExp
var string = 'Me     &  You';
let value = /\S*(&|#|%)\S*/;//for example
let resssC = string.split(value )...
```

How can I get the required outputs? Is it a problem with regexp or is there anything else?

Answer (score 1):

As i thought you have to replace only &

```
string.replace(/\&/g,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just that simple:?

```
console.log(string.split("&").join(""))
```